# I am trying to play a video dynamically when user clicks on a list element with angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, video, typescript

I am reading in a list of videos and when a user clicks on a video I want to play that video in their browser. I am using angular2

this is my html

```
  <div>
    <ul>
        <li id="videoList" *ngFor="let videoName of videoNames"><a (click)="playVideo(videoName, sopJson)" href="javascript: void(0)">{{videoName}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="videoPlayer" [hidden]="hiddenVideo">
        <video width="800" height="600" controls>
            <source [src]="sopVideoUrl">
            </video>
            <p>{{videoDescriptions}}</p>
    </div>
```

I pass the id correctly then this is my playvideo method

```
playVideo(id: String, sopJson: String){
 this.hiddenVideo = false; 


this.sopVideoUrl = `http://localhost:8080/${id}`; 


 for(let i = 0; i < sopJson.length; i++){
     let name = sopJson[i]; 
     if(id == name[0].Name){
         if(name[1].Descrption != ""){
           let description = name[1].Descrption;
           this.videoDescriptions.push(description); 
         }

     }
 }


/*
  let sopStrVideo = '<video width="800" height="600" controls>' +
                '<source src="http://localhost:8080/'+id+'">'+
                '</video>'






     document.getElementById('videoPlayer').innerHTML = sopStrVideo; 
     */

}
```

I am setting the source on my variable. it shows in my dom the src is set correctly but it does not play. however if I inject html using javascript this works fine... does anyone know why this does not work? Also on the description part when I click a video it keeps adding to the description. instead of replacing the one that is there.

[image]

this should just say toy plane as the description but every time I click it adds another toy plane.

[image]

Comment: `this.videoDescriptions.push(description);` is an array so the behavior is expected. declare/change `videoDescriptions : string` and `this.videoDescriptions = description` instead.

Comment: duh idk why I didn't catch that thanks that worked

Comment: why was this voted as a bad question? you helped me with one part I figured the other out for myself I am sure that some people may have the same problem when working with angular2

Comment: I hope "You" is used in general here instead of pointing out to me. Lol.  I just came here to see why I was notified. If someone in the community finds it useful they'll bump it up. You shouldn't really give this downvote too much importance... Just code!!

Comment: you are correct searching thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so my problem with this was in my html side instead of using html above and trying to bind with the source html element. Using Angular 2 binding  I should of just used this html code and it works

```
<div id="videoPlayer" [hidden]="hiddenVideo">
           <video width="800" height="600" controls [src]="sopVideoUrl">
                </video>
                <p>{{videoDescriptions}}</p>
        </div>
```